# how to display a random value from an array of objects in an React view

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I created a REST API and fetched the data within a useEffect hook. I stored that data in a state called posts and wanted to display a random value from that state and display when someones click a button. Every time a user clicks the button I want it to display a different value. Everything works until I click the button a second time and then it pops up an error saying posts are undefined. Below is the entire component. I need help with making that error going away because I expect a new post to appear every time a user clicks the button.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {
        const fetchingPosts = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/posts");
        const posts = await fetchingPosts.json();

        setPosts(posts);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const random = posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)];
    setPosts(random);
  };
  console.log(posts);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      <span>{posts.quote}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already initialized post as an array of object conatining n number of different posts

Reassigning its value to just one post inside `handleClick` will cause `posts` to loose it's initial state

So just create another hook that will be an empty string initially and will get a different random post from array `posts` after every click!

Something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [onePost, setOnePost] = useState(''); //one more hook for storing current random post

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {
        const fetchingPosts = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/posts");
        const posts = await fetchingPosts.json();

        setPosts(posts);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const random = posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)];
    setOnePost(random);//value assigned here
  };
  console.log(posts);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      <span>{onePost.quote}</span> //print onePost instead of Post
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```